# How to use event.preventDefault() on form submit as 'event' in javascript are now deprecated?

Tags: events, dom-events, addeventlistener, preventdefault, onsubmit

I am getting a warning for my below code saying that 'event' in javascript have been deprecated.

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(event)">
   ...
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function handleFormSubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

I tried removing the 'event' from the attribute value. But this gives an error saying "event not defined".

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="handleFormSubmit()">
   ...
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function handleFormSubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

I also tried the addEventListener() method and it does work as expected. But I am looking for a way to assign the function using inline attribute.

Comment: If you have to write the logic in your function `handleFormSubmit()` anyway, why don't you want to use `addEventListener()` method?